# Access Denied. Not Authorized to use this application - when trying to instantiate a com+ object intermittent error

Tags: vb6, com+

Set up:

Server running Windows 2012.

Application with user interface exe written in VB6 is installed on a server and all users connect via RDP to run it.

Business object dll created with VB6 installed in COM+ on the same server.
When the application starts, it instantiate the dll.

Issue:

From time to time, and more so recently, the application encounters an error with the description
"Access Denied. Not Authorized to use this application". The fix so far was to reboot the server.

At this point, I am able to point to COM+. After getting the error, it seems that the object in COM+ is not active (not spinning). When I Clicked on "Shut down", and open the application again, it works fine.

It is intermittent. A week can go by without having the issue, and sometimes it happens more than once a day.

Questions:

Did anyone experienced similar issue, and what was the cause and the fix?

Can you suggest how to further troubleshoot this issue? Is it resources issues - memory, cpu, network, security update?

Thanks

Moshe

Comment: Try removing DLL from COM+ and register with regsvr32 - the DLL with “remote” component of the application probably is not doing anything useful being local COM+ application anyway.

Comment: Thanks for responding! To my understanding, COM+ is needed for transactions which we use?

Comment: Could be but I highly doubt it. It's very complicated and brittle to do distributed transactions using COM+. Usually placing an unattended VB6 DLL under transaction server has a lot to do with cargo-culting and some imaginary benefits for remoting.

Comment: This application was running smoothly for years in COM+ without any issue. Number of users hover around 30-40 with a high volume of transactions. I did find out that one user who recently start working with the application, is constantly logging out and logging in again. 30 or more times a day for some odd reason. I asked him to stop and I will watch it for the next 24-48 hours. 
If this will not help, I will start making changes to some properties such as pooling and recycling. I am still waiting to see if anyone here might have encounter a similar issue and share solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who will stumble upon this question:
It turned out to be an issue with our code and not an issue in COM+.
We are using MTS property group management to save a unique token created when a user logs in and authenticate when app is calling our dll sending this  token. We authenticate it by getting an array stored in the mts propery group. All tokens have a time to leave. For many years it worked perfectly. It start failing because we got a duplicate token which broke our authentication code. We believe that it had to do with new users who opened our application multiple times and very rapidly. This also explains why it was so intermittent. Once we discovered that, we were able to recreate the issue.
The solution was to add a GUID to the token to ensure uniqueness.
It had been now more than 3 days with out getting the error.